# Validate User Entry

Tags: excel, validation, vba

I am trying to run a marco that check the cells users have entered and makes sure they are not blank. I am having a hard time with one cell. I want the user to be limited to entering only 2 letters and I want it to check to make sure no numbers were entered in that cell otherwise throw up an error message and exit sub. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
If Worksheets("New PN").Range("B12").Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Date cannot be left empty.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Entry Error"
Exit Sub
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **THIS!**

```
cellContent = Worksheets("New PN").Range("B12").Value
leftCC = Left(cellContent, 1)
rightCC = Right(cellContent, 1)
If Len(cellContent) <> 2 Then

        MsgBox "There needs to be 2 characters."
        Exit Sub

ElseIf (Asc(leftCC) < 65 Or Asc(leftCC) > 122 _
         Or (Asc(leftCC) > 90 And Asc(leftCC) < 97)) _
    Or _
       (Asc(rightCC) < 65 Or Asc(rightCC) > 122 _
         Or (Asc(rightCC) > 90 And Asc(rightCC) < 97)) Then

        MsgBox "Both characters can only be letters."
        Exit Sub

End If
```

Might be big and scary, but it will get the job done 100%.

**EDIT :** The `Asc(char)` formula returns the ascii number for the character supplied. The outer limits of a-z and A-Z are 65 and 122, however some non-characters are included in the middle (namely [, \, ], ^, _, `). Hence the horrid if.

Comment: Hello BernardSaucier thank you for the comment. I am still having a problem where I can still enter a number and a letter and the macro will run. For example, I can input "C1" and it will run. Do you have any suggestion on how to fix this. Thanks!

Comment: Updated answer, go ahead and try it!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
my_string = Worksheets("New PN").Range("B12").Value

If Len(my_string) = 2 And Left(my_string, 1) Like "[A-Za-z]" _
    And Right(my_string, 1) Like "[A-Za-z]" Then
    '~~execute what you want here
Else
    MsgBox "Invalid input" & vbNewLine & "Enter 2 LETTERS only"
End If
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Looks great, but the only this is : not a number doesn't mean a letter.

Comment: Wow, when I saw your correction I wondered if your regular expression would work (didn't think it needed a comma in there) so I tried it out and it didn't (terrible copy-paste; missed the first line), while it actually does. So I went ahead and finished typing my answer out xD. +1 for beating me to the punch. Twice.

Comment: @BernardSaucier haha you're approach is good as well. and also pointing out the details on ASCII but not very well versed with that so i resort to reg ex. Thanks for pointing out the flaw in my first solution :D and thanks for correcting the `comma`. it shouldn't be there. :D

Comment: You shouldn't have changed `[a-zA-Z]` because it has a different meaning than `[A-z]` (which includes those random characters separating upper case and lower case characters).